# My Work Fly Away This is not just FAIR?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, self-answer, unaccepted-answer

On this Question:

[How to unit test a Controller action using the Response property in ASP.NET 5 (MVC 6)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35319501/how-to-unit-test-a-controller-action-using-the-response-property-in-asp-net-5-m/35319704)

Question was about how to mock a private setter: And I believe, I gave the right answer with a few more options and I sacrifice my private time for this. But the questioner gave himself answer point. Please evaluate the case and tell me is this fair?

Comment: Well, who was promising _fairness_ for accepted answers? It's the OP's business to accept what they want.

Comment: Since you had perfect duplicate (I voted as dup) - you should have added comment about it and possibly move on. Alternatively adding answer to duplicate target may be better approach.

Comment: Side note: bringing up question on META may increase votes on all linked q&a posts as well as decrease voting activity (as some people will not vote on posts brought up on meta to avoid meta-effect).

Answer (score 17):

Life isn't fair. Askers are free to give the checkmark to whomever they want; there isn't a policy of any kind that allows us to move it to the 'right' answer.

Note that, since they are the asker, they won't receive any reputation by accepting their answer. It also won't change the order answers are displayed in.

The only thing you've been deprived of here is 15 reputation. That's nothing.

Comment: I'm not after 15 reputation point. This is annoying don't u think? I'm kindly gave my time and my effort to help this fellow. But thanks anyway...

Comment: @efaruk It's annoying, definitely. Some people are simply ungrateful. Don't take it too seriously, it's just a random person on the Internet - there's no reason to respond to them at all. I'd just drop it and move on; the next person you help will likely be nicer.

Comment: I demand an Undo! I deserve all 15 of those points! Undo the answer accept! On a more serious note, I think you're being a bit presumptuous here with regard to the intentions of the asker. Perhaps they legitimately determined that their solution *worked better for them, in their project* than efaruk's answer did. So although they appreciated his answer, they accepted their own. This is not only their prerogative, but it would have been objectively the right choice.

Comment: wait.... if you do it to help, why care if you get the checkmark or not? Your (didn't read it, but lets say good and better) answer will help MANY more people with that question who google and come to SO with it :).

Comment: @CodyGray Definitely. I'm purposely giving efaruk the benefit of the doubt here, mostly because ASP isn't my expertise and I have no business judging those answers.

Comment: @CodyGray, Actually I gave the same asnwer (Not just right) But I did'nt gave the exact line of codes. I just show him this is the way: you can take this way to solve your problem. This is not mean work better or greater. Please pay attention to question it self. I can discuss with you this subject in architectural aspect. But I don't want to do that...

Comment: @efaruk I don't know what you are talking about. But it doesn't matter what I think. It matters what the person who asked the question thinks. They are the one who gets to make the decision about which answer to accept.

Comment: @CodyGray you said: "This is not only their prerogative, but it would have been objectively the right choice." I'm telling this is not objectively decided, this is what we are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You could look the other way around : If you leave your answer it will probably suck reps out of the question anyway, perhaps or perhaps not stealing upvotes and attention from the accepted answer, even if the accepted answer is more correct (I dont say that it is, but many times the accepted answer *is* the best answer to the question) - is that fair?

A good well formed answer will eventually earn upvotes, that is for sure - there is even a Populist badge, so if you have written a good answer you can just sit back and wait for redress :)

Comment: *"it will probably suck reps out of the question anyway"* What? Why would an answer suck reputation away from the question? You can vote on each one independently of the other.

Comment: @CodyGray - yes you _can_, have you ever seen older questions with multiple answers where each answer had the same vote count ..?

Comment: @davidkonrad your answer says suck rep from the QUESTION, your comment talks about ANSWERS... I'm confuzzled :(